# reading multiple files quickly in R

Tags: r

I have over 10000 csv files and I need to do a Fast Fourier Transformation on each column of each csv file. I have access to 1000 cores. What should be the fastest way?

Currently I have a for loop reading each file sequentially and using the `apply(data, 2, FFT)` function. How would I do so? I tried doing `clusterapply(1:10000, cl, transformation)`. In the transformation function, I have read csv. It still takes a long time to do all the reading. Do anyone of you know a faster way?

Comment: This depends more on your disk storage system/setup than R itself, and all the CPUs in the world won't help if your data has to be accessed serially. Is your data distributed on a cluster _storage_ system?

Comment: Instead of having each thread reading a file, have you tried processing the columns within a file in parallel? It could be as simple as `mclapply(data, fft)`.

Comment: fread in data.tables is much faster than read.csv

Comment: my data is in a high performance computer. So I hope the data is not being accesses serially. How would I know if it is or not?

Comment: @NealFultz, can you elaborate a little more, so I understand what you are saying exactly. I am currently using 15 clusters. Each cluser will read a file. Once it reads the file it will then do an apply fft function onto each column. at the end the 15 clusters join the file, and I go onto the next set of 15 files. This is being doing sequentially (every 15 files). Can this be avoided?

Comment: You should post working code for parallel apply's on your machine. Then people can suggest improvements if they exist. I do think you need to investigate the `fread` suggestion. There's no reason I can think of that would prevent its distribution.

Answer (score 4):

I would think that the fastest way would be to `mclapply` and `fread`.

```
#Bring in libraries
library(parallel)
library(data.table)

#Find all csv files in your folder
csv.list = list.files(pattern="*.csv")

#Create function to read in data and perform fft on each column
read.fft <- function(x) {
    data <- fread(x)
    result <- data[, lapply(.SD,fft)]
return(result)
}

#Apply function using multiple cores
all.results <- mclapply(csv.list,read.fft,mc.cores=10)
```

If it makes sense for you to take a random sample of each dataset, I would highly suggest changing the `read.fft` function to use the `shuf` command. It will spend up your read-in time by quite a bit.

```
#Create function to read in data and perform fft
read.fft <- function(x) {
    data <- fread(paste0("shuf -n 10000",x)) #Takes random sample of 10000 rows
    result <- data[, lapply(.SD,fft)]
return(result)
}
```