# downloading data and saving data to a folder in batches

Tags: r

I have 200,000 links that I am trying to download, I have tried downloading it all in one go but I ran into memory issues.

I am trying to create a function which will download 1000 links at a time and save them in a folder.

Packages:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(edgarWebR)
```

A small sample of the data is as follows:

Data 1:

```
urls_to_parse <- c("https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1750/000104746918004978/a2236183z10-k.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1750/000104746917004528/a2232622z10-k.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1750/000104746916014299/a2228768z10-k.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1750/000104746915006136/a2225345z10-k.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1750/000104746914006243/a2220733z10-k.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1750/000104746913007797/a2216052z10-k.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1750/000104746912007300/a2210166z10-k.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1750/000104746911006302/a2204709z10-k.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1750/000104746910006500/a2199382z10-k.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1750/000104746909006783/a2193700z10-k.htm"
)
```

I then apply the following function to download these 10 links

```
parsed_files <- map(urls_to_parse, possibly(parse_filing, otherwise = NA))
```

Which stores it as a nice list, I can then apply `names(parsed_files) <- urls_to_parse` to name the lists as the links from where they were downloading them from. I can also use `output <- plyr::ldply(parsed_files, data.frame)` to store everything in a nice data frame.

Using the below data, how could I create batches to download the data in say batches of 10?

What I have currently:

```
start = 1
end = 100

output <- NULL
output_fin <- NULL

for(i in start:end){
  output[[i]] <- map(urls_to_parse[[i]], possibly(parse_filing, otherwise = NA))
  names(output) <- urls_to_parse[start:end]
  save(output_fin, file = paste0("C:/Users/Downloads/data/",i, "output.RData"))
}
```

I am sure there is a better way using a function, since this code breaks for some of the results.

More data: - 100 links

```
urls_to_parse <- c("https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1750/000104746918004978/a2236183z10-k.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1750/000104746917004528/a2232622z10-k.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1750/000104746916014299/a2228768z10-k.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1750/000104746915006136/a2225345z10-k.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1750/000104746914006243/a2220733z10-k.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1750/000104746913007797/a2216052z10-k.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1750/000104746912007300/a2210166z10-k.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1750/000104746911006302/a2204709z10-k.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1750/000104746910006500/a2199382z10-k.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1750/000104746909006783/a2193700z10-k.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1750/000104746908008126/a2186742z10-k.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1750/000110465907055173/a07-18543_110k.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1750/000110465906047248/a06-15961_110k.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1750/000110465905033688/a05-12324_110k.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1750/000104746904023905/a2140220z10-k.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1750/000104746903028005/a2116671z10-k.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1750/000091205702033450/a2087919z10-k.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/61478/000095012310108231/c61492e10vk.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/61478/000095015208010514/n48172e10vk.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/61478/000095013707018659/c22309e10vk.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/61478/000095013707000193/c11187e10vk.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/61478/000095013406000594/c01109e10vk.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/61478/000120677405000032/d16006.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/61478/000120677404000013/d13773.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/61478/000104746903001075/a2097401z10-k.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/61478/000091205702001614/a2067550z10-k.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/319126/000115752308008030/a5800571.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/319126/000115752307009801/a5515869.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/319126/000115752306009238/a5227919.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/730469/000073046908000102/alpharmainc_10k.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/730469/000073046907000017/alo10k2006.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/730469/000073046906000027/alo10k2005.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/730469/000073046905000021/alo10k2004final.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/730469/000073046904000058/alo10k2003master.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/730469/000073046903000001/alo10k.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/730469/000073046902000004/alo10k2001.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/730469/000073046901500003/alo.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/4515/000000620118000009/a10k123117.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/4515/000119312517051216/d286458d10k.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/4515/000119312516474605/d78287d10k.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/4515/000119312515061145/d829913d10k.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/4515/000000620114000004/aagaa10k-20131231.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/6201/000000620113000023/amr-10kx20121231.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/6201/000119312512063516/d259681d10k.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/6201/000095012311014726/d78201e10vk.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/6201/000000620110000006/ar123109.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/6201/000000620109000009/ar120810k.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/6201/000000451508000014/ar022010k.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/6201/000095013407003888/d43815e10vk.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/6201/000095013406003715/d33303e10vk.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/6201/000095013405003726/d22731e10vk.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/6201/000095013404002668/d12953e10vk.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/6201/000104746903013301/a2108197z10-k.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/65695/000095013407003823/h42902e10vk.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/65695/000095012906002343/h31028e10vk.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/65695/000095012905002955/h22337e10vk.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/3197/000156459018005085/cece-10k_20171231.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/3197/000156459017004264/cece-10k_20161231.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/3197/000156459016015157/cece-10k_20151231.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/3197/000119312515095828/d864880d10k.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/3197/000119312514098407/d661608d10k.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/3197/000119312513109153/d444138d10k.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/3197/000119312512119293/d293768d10k.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/3197/000119312511067373/d10k.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/3197/000119312510069639/d10k.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/3197/000119312509055504/d10k.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/3197/000119312508058939/d10k.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/3197/000119312507071909/d10k.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/3197/000119312506068031/d10k.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/3197/000119312505077739/d10k.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/3197/000119312504052176/d10k.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/2601/000110465910047121/a10-16705_110k.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/2601/000114420409046933/v159572_10k.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/2601/000110465906060737/a06-19311_110k.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/2601/000104746905022854/a2162888z10-k.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/2601/000104746904028585/a2143353z10-k.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/2601/000104746903031974/a2119476z10-k.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/859163/000143774918010388/avx20180331_10k.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/859163/000085916317000028/avx-20170331x10k.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/859163/000085916316000079/avx-20160331x10k.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/859163/000085916315000024/avx-20150331x10k.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/859163/000085916314000035/avx-20140331x10k.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/859163/000085916313000022/avx-20130331x10k.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/859163/000085916312000024/avxform10kfy12.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/859163/000085916311000013/avxform10kfy11.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/859163/000085916310000020/avxform10kfy10.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/859163/000085916309000117/form10kfy09.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/859163/000085916308000192/form10qq1fy09.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/859163/000085916308000101/form10kfy08.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/859163/000085916307000122/form10kfy07.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/859163/000085916306000102/avxfy06form10-k.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/859163/000085916305000094/fy0510k.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/859163/000085916304000091/fy0410k.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/859163/000085916303000020/fy0310k.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/859163/000085916302000007/r10k-0302.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/7286/000076462218000018/pnw2017123110-k.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/7286/000076462217000010/pnw2016123110-k.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/7286/000076462216000087/pnw2015123110-k.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/7286/000076462215000013/pnw12311410-k.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/7286/000110465914012068/a13-25897_110k.htm"
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Looping over to do batch job as you showed is a bad idea. If you have a 1000s of files to be downloaded, how do you recover from errors?

The performance is not solely depend on your computer's configuration, but the network performance is crucial.

Here are couple of suggestions.

**Option 1**

- partition all URLs in to batches to be able to download them parallelly. The number of files to be downloaded could be equal to number of cores in your computer. Look at this question; [reading multiple files quickly in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27051856/reading-multiple-files-quickly-in-r)
- store these batches in a queue objects - For ex: using a package like https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dequer/dequer.pdf
- pop the queue and use the batch of URLs in your parallel file download function.
- Use a retryable file download function like in -- [HTTP error 400 in R, error handling, How to retry instead of forcing to stop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48067906/http-error-400-in-r-error-handling-how-to-retry-instead-of-forcing-to-stop)
- Once the queue is completed, move to the next partition.
- wrap the whole operation in a retryable loop. For example; [How to retry a statement on error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20770497/how-to-retry-a-statement-on-error)

Why do I use a queue? Because you could retry on error easily.

A pseudo code

```
file_url_partitions <- partion_as_batches(all_urls, batch_size) 
attempts = 3
while( file_url_partitions is not empty && attempt <= 3 ) {
  batch = file_url_partitions.pop()

  tryCatch({
   download_parallel(batch)
  }, some_exception = function(se) {
    file_url_partitions.push(batch)
    attemp = attempt+1 
  })
}
```

**Note: I don't have access to R studio/environment now hence no way to try.**

**Option 2**
Download files separately using a download manager/similar and use downloaded files.

Some useful resources: 
https://www.r-bloggers.com/r-with-parallel-computing-from-user-perspectives/ 
http://adv-r.had.co.nz/beyond-exception-handling.html